# How to view blob data in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I read blob data in  Oracle SQL Developer. It is stored in byte[] format.  Is there any possibility to read in string format.

Comment: text is not readable form

Answer (score 34):

Follow these steps in `Oracle SQL Developer` -

1. Open data window of your table.
2. The BLOB cell will be named as **(BLOB)**.
3. Right click the cell.
4. You will see a **pencil** icon. Click on it.
5. It will open a **blob editor** window.
6. You would find two check boxes against the option **View as : Image or Text**.
7. Select the appropriate check box.
8. If above step is still convincing, then use the **Download** option.

**Update**

OP says "*text is not understandable manner it is showing �� �� like this* "

Probably, the **locale-specific NLS characterset** doesn't support those characters. It might also be that those are **Multi-Byte** characters. I would suggest, `SPOOL` the result to an `HTML` file, open it with your `browser`, you could view the content as most of the browsers are capable of displaying multiple charactersets.

You could do something like this from SQL*Plus -

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL report.html
select substr(clob_column, 1, 32767) from table_name...
SPOOL OFF
```

**Update 2**

Regarding SPOOL as HTML, test case -

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL D:\report.html
SELECT substr(ename, 1, 5) ename FROM emp where rownum <=5;
SPOOL OFF
```

Works perfectly for me, html file opens up with my browser, look at the screenshot -

[image]

Comment: What is readable format for you, please explain. I cannot address such a broad term.

Comment: What happens when you just do a `SUBSTR` over the column? At least you can view the first 32767 characters.

Comment: text is not understandable manner it is showing  �� �� like this

Comment: I am alredy using that substring query iam getting text like this ��srcom.hexgen.orm.PortfolioAlloc/���ZisActiveL_hexGenEntityVersiont3Lcom/hexgen/core/orm/basetypes/HexGenEntityVersion;L
allocationPertLjava/math/BigDecimal;L

Comment: Because your NLS character set doesn't support those characters. Try to `SPOOL` it to an `HTML` file and see the content.

Comment: how to spool it in html can u pls explin

Comment: SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL report.html
select substr(blob_column, 1, 32767) from HEXGEN_HIS
SPOOL OFF

Comment: At step 3, I have to Double-Left click in the cell to see the pencil.  (I have version 4.0.2)

Comment: there is no pencil!

Comment: @java-addict301 choose "Single Record View". Then you will see the pencil button in the popup that appears.

Comment: If the file is a zip file, make sure to save it as zip while using download option. Also, I figured that the substr approach doesn't work on BLOB columns. It can be used for CLOB columns.

Comment: Double Click for me.